# Programming in Java using by Spark

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark

I know how to configure environment to use Scala and Python along with Spar, but I have a problem along with Java.

What is the easiest way to configure an Spark environment using by Java? (Guide - Installation Steps)

Sinecirely
K.

@Update

I have found a great introduction to Apache Spark using by Java, so the problem is solved. The link to the tutorial is below:

[Apache Spark Tutorial–Run your First Spark Program](http://I%20want%20to%20convert%20a%20couple%20of%20columns%20to%20Dense%20Vectors%20using%20by%20PySpark.%20While%20using%20Vector%20Assembler%20for%20some%20cases%20I%20get%20Sparse%20Vectors.%20These%20cases%20occur%20if%20a%20vector%20contains%20mostly%20zeros.%20I%20want%20to%20omit%20additional%20transformation%20step,%20and%20as%20output%20get%20only%20Dense%20Vectors.%20Could%20you%20please%20give%20me%20an%20advice%20on%20how%20can%20I%20efficiently%20do%20that?%20%20Here%20is%20my%20exemplary%20code%20which%20transforms%20specified%20columns%20to%20dense%20and%20sparse%20vectors.)

Sinecirely
K.

Answer (score 3):

You should pay more attention to official page. Watch this http://spark.apache.org/examples.html. There're examples in Python, Scala and Java, which is what you want.

Also, here you have the [official Java API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html). Just download the .jar and you're ready to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark in the JVM ( across Java, Clojure, Scala and more ).
Additionally, Spark provides a Java Interface through `JavaSparkContext` and `org.apache.spark.api.java`

> The Spark Java API exposes all the Spark features available in the Scala version to Java. To learn the basics of Spark, we recommend reading through the Scala programming guide first; it should be easy to follow even if you don’t know Scala. This guide will show how to use the Spark features described there in Java.
>   The Spark Java API is defined in the org.apache.spark.api.java package, and includes a JavaSparkContext for initializing Spark and JavaRDD classes, which support the same methods as their Scala counterparts but take Java functions and return Java data and collection types. The main differences have to do with passing functions to RDD operations (e.g. map) and handling RDDs of different types, as discussed next.

Found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/java-programming-guide.html)